# how to solve db2 code: -104, SQL State: 42601

Tags: sql, db2, dbvisualizer

```
--/
BEGIN
     FOR V AS MYCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,NAME,AGE FROM PEOPLE
     DO
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME,AGE) VALUES(V.NAME,V.AGE);
        END;
     END FOR;
END;
/
```

DB tool is Dbvisualizer 10.0.1, so I need "--/" and "/"

> Message: [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601] An unexpected token "V" was found following "BEGIN FOR ". Expected tokens may include: "JOIN".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29
>   Help plz.

Comment: What’s the Db2 version and platform? Have you tried to find the place in DBVisualizer, where you can change the statement delimiter from `;` to `/`?

Comment: Your code fragment works correctly in my DbVisualizer , but I have the *current* version of Dbviz - consider installing the latest build ( 10.0.24). Otherwise your code fragment differs from what Db2 is getting.

Answer (score 0):

In your query tool, set the statement terminator to something that is not ';'. 
E.g. use `@`

```
BEGIN
 FOR V AS MYCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,NAME,AGE FROM PEOPLE
 DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME,AGE) VALUES(V.NAME,V.AGE);
    END;
 END FOR;
END
@
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use different Statement Delimiter / Terminator to run compound statements.
Every client tool has its own methods of setting it.
Dbvisualizer:

Tools\Tool Properties\SQL Commander\Statement Delimiters:
SQL Statement Delimiter:
SQL Statement Delimiter 1: @
SQL Statement Delimiter 2: @
Using the DBMS Output Tab:

Only in DbVisualizer DbVisualizer Pro edition.
This feature is only available in the DbVisualizer Pro edition.

BEGIN
FOR V AS MYCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,NAME,AGE FROM PEOPLE
DO
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME,AGE) VALUES(V.NAME,V.AGE);
END;
END FOR;
END
@